# Formatting SQL Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 100 update statements of following format:

```
UPDATE Eli
SET UserId = @ID, UpdateDate = @DATE, Indicator = 'C'
WHERE Isdel = 'N'
    AND TId = 56260563
    AND Indicator = 'A'
    AND ENumber = 21848963
    AND CNumber = 111248400
    AND PBDate = '2013-10-01'
```

how do i put the above update statement in single line, like the below-

```
UPDATE Eli SET UserId = @ID, UpdateDate = @DATE, Indicator = 'C'WHERE Isdel = 'N'       AND TId = 56260563  AND Indicator = 'A' AND ENumber = 21848963  AND CNumber = 111248400     AND PBDate = '2013-10-01'
```

Comment: ... It kind of looks like you already put it in a single line, no?  What am I missing?

Comment: why dont you just use merge so you dont have to continuously keep saying and!. all you would have to do is give input values. What is this question asking? you already did the work though

Comment: I have 100 update statments like this. instead of doing it manually, i want a way to format them using sql editor.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to offer much help here because it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all, why? Secondly, can you use a text editor like Sublime Text to find line breaks and replace them with spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a text editor like [Notepadd++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or any other advance editor, and runa  replace of CR+LF for " " (a blank space).

[image]

Also supported by SSMS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why format a bunch of statements?  Instead, load a table with data and use `JOIN`.  Here is an example:

```
select @id as id, @date as updatedate, 'N' as isdel, 56260563 as tid, 
       'A' as indicator, 111248400 as CNumber,
       cast('2013-10-01' as date) as PBDate
into table_toupdate;

UPDATE e
    SET UserId = tu.id, UpdateDate = tu.updatedate, Indicator = 'C'
    FROM Eli e JOIN
         table_toupdate tu
         ON e.isdel = tu.isdel and
            e.tid = tu.tid and
            e.enumber = tu.enumber and
            e.cnumber = tu.cnumber and
            e.pbdate = tu.pbdate;
```

You can then load the update table with lots of rows and just run one update statement.